# SMTP Mail not displaying Date in Mail Header

Tags: php, email

I am using smtp for mailing purpose.

Here is my code

```
$from = "Koh<projects@bzinfo.in>";
$to = $sendmail['Email'];
$subject = $row["Title"];
$body = $row["Message"];
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host,'auth' => true,'username' => $username,'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

It is always displaying the the Sent time as none

What can i do to display the time in the header of the email.

Regards

Carol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the date parameter in the header array of your email

i.e., `'Date'=> date('r', time())`

So your header array should be

```
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject, 'Date'=> date('r', time());
```

Here is the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) page which gives you SMTP transport example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)